# react-router routes not giving the desired output when rendered not showing anything on the webpage

Tags: reactjs, django, react-router, react-router-dom

I am a beginner in react and i am using routes for basic routing of components on my homepage
This is the code on my homepage component but still it shows nothing on my webpage when I run the server

```
import React,{ Component } from "react";
import RoomJoinPage from "./RoomJoinPage";
import CreateRoomPage from "./CreateRoomPage";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link, Redirect, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

export default class HomePage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <Router>
              <Routes>
                <Route exact path='/' element={ <HomePage/> }><h1>This is the home page</h1></Route>
                <Route exact path='/join' element={ <RoomJoinPage/> }></Route>
                <Route exact path='/create' element={ <CreateRoomPage/> } ></Route>
              </Routes>
          </Router>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I have used webpack configurations to create the app as I am using react and Django. When I searched for solution on stack somebody commented on a post as if you are using webpack configurations for manually setting up the project it requires `devServer : {historyApiFallback: true,}` for react routes to work so what should I do please help me I've been stuck on this part from last two days If the above solution is right then please let me know where to write that following statement to make the react routes work...

Comment: Only issues I see in your code snippet are (1) there is no `Switch` component exported in RRDv6, and (2) `Route` components don't render anything other than other `Route` components as children.

Comment: yes ! because Switch is not used in react-router-don v6. Routes is used in V6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are using Browser Router as Router. One thing I would try is to use BrowserRouter without using as Router, just like this `<BrowserRouter> </BrowserRouter>.`
Another thing that I would try is to use HashRouter instead of BrowserRouter, and use it in the file index.js like this:

```
 ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <HashRouter>
            <App />
    </HashRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

And your HomePage file should look like this:

```
import React,{ Component } from "react";
import RoomJoinPage from "./RoomJoinPage";
import CreateRoomPage from "./CreateRoomPage";
import { Switch, Route, Link, Redirect, Routes } from "react-router-dom";   

export default class HomePage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }  


    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          
              <Routes>
                <Route exact path='/' element={ <HomePage/> }><h1>This is the home page</h1></Route>
                <Route exact path='/join' element={ <RoomJoinPage/> }></Route>
                <Route exact path='/create' element={ <CreateRoomPage/> } ></Route>
              </Routes>
          
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

If anything of this works, please share the version of react router dom and react if it's possible. Previously I also had problems of this style with RRD.

Comment: I tried your code it was giving me the same issue, but your code is perfectly fine as per my knowledge. I uninstalled react-router-dom v6 and reinstalled V5.2.0 and worked well, I got the output. Thankyou for the help !